# Accessing Postgraphile (as a library) with Apollo client from the same server

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, postgraphile

I have postgraphile running on an express server (as a library)

```
export const postGraphileServer = () => {
  return postgraphile(process.env.DB_DSN, 'public', options);
};
```

Express:

```
app.use(postGraphileServer());
```

Using the codegen introspection plugin I am generating a `graphql.schema.json` and everything works correctly when GQL is accessed externally via an http link.
yml snippit:

```
  packages/graphql/src/generated/graphql.schema.json:
    plugins:
      - 'introspection'
```

I have a use case for exposing a REST endpoint on the express server which would take a payload and create a row in Postgres.  What I would like to do is access Postgraphile directly (without a network hop) to avoid auth - I believe using [schema only](https://www.graphile.org/postgraphile/usage-schema/)

From what I have read the way to do this is via a `SchemaLink`.  I've tried something like:

```
const clientSchema = buildClientSchema(schema as unknown as IntrospectionQuery);

// Make executable schema from client schema
const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: clientSchema,
});

return (this.#_apolloClient = new ApolloClient({ 
  ssrMode: true,
  link: new SchemaLink({ schema: executableSchema }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
}));
```

Where `schema` is the codegen generated `graphql.schema.json` file. I believe the issue I have is I also need to pass the resolvers to `makeExecutableSchema` so that Postgraphile knows how to query / mutate - currently it silently fails but does nothing.

Am I on the correct path here and is there a way to access the generated resolvers from postgraphile (or do I need to manually create them for this specific use case?)

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/graphile/starter/blob/main/%40app/lib/src/GraphileApolloLink.ts

Comment: Thank you! I think this gets me what I need.  I'll update with an answer once I have a cleaned up sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so with the help of Benjie I was able to get this working using `GraphileApolloLink.ts`.  Since this link grabs the context and schema from the middleware itself, there is no need to try and build a schema from the `schema.graphql.json` introspection file.

My requirements differed slightly so I removed the mutation check inside `GraphileApolloLink.ts`.

For completeness, I was able to initialize the `ApolloClient` with simply

```js
get #apolloClient(): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
  if (this.#_apolloClient) {
    return this.#_apolloClient;
  }

  const _link = new GraphileApolloLink({
    req: this.request,
    res: this.response,
    // Getter for the middleware object passed into Express
    postgraphileMiddleware: postGraphileMiddleware(),
  });

  return (this.#_apolloClient = new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: true,
    link: _link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  }));
}
```

And query the data successfully using the queries/mutations generated by codegen as expected.